# Check if a certain value has a corresponding value

Tags: r

I have a vector of uppercase letters.

I want to check if each `A` value in the vector has a corresponding `B` value. It does not have to just after `A` value but has to be after `A` value. And also check that  every `B` value has a corresponding `A` value. It does not have to be just before the `B` value but should be anywhere in the vector `x` before the `B`. If this is not true for an `A` value or a `B` value, then, this `A` or `B` value should be changed to `C`.

For ex:

```
y <- c("A", "B",  "B", "C", "C", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B")
```

`y` vector has two `B` values. Since, the fourth `B` value has no corresponding `A` value, therefore, this `B` value should be changed to `C` value. The desired output for this vector should be:

```
y <- c("A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "C", "C", "B", "C")
```

How can I do this in R. It would be highly appreciated if it could be done using `lapply`.

Edit: Also, between an `A` and a `B` value, if there is a value, it should only be `C`.

Comment: `y` is just `x` with an added "B" to its end. Do you want an example with the x or y vector? Please clarify that and also share a proper example of the desired output.

Comment: That is only just an example. Sometimes there is a vector like `y <- c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "C", "B")`.

Comment: ok, but for this y vector, what is the desired output?

Comment: why do you say the second "B" has no corresponding value? Wont `y[5]` be considered a "corresponding A"?

Comment: I have added the desired output in the question. Also, sorry, I meant the fourth `B` value, not the second.

Comment: You haver included several different vectors in your question, but only one is needed. Please remove Theo unecessary ones and keep only x, y or z

Comment: I have edited the question to only have `y`.

Comment: After extensive prompting for a clear question, I eventually gave up on asking for further clarifications, and voted to close this question down. Please consider reviewing [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to make a good reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), carefully review the question, and edit accordingly, to increase the chances of getting it reopened.

Comment: inconsistencies in the question: first "B" is replaced for no reason, the "fourth" B is said to be replaced but the positions are all wrong, the concept of "correspondence" between As and Bs is poorly defined.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R shines in vectorized methods. This question highly depends on results of groups and investigating what is in those groups. This answer provides expected results of the one example given, but I do not believe that it is a great example of R code. For anything like this, I would implement in [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp) because it would 1) be more performant and 2) make me understand immediately that the solution might not have an idiomatic R approach.

```r
y <- c("A", "B",  "B", "C", "C", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B")
new_y = y

which_A = which(y == "A")
which_B = which(y == "B")

for (i in seq_along(which_A)) {
  start_ind = which_A[i]
  end_ind = if (i == length(which_A)) length(y) else which_A[i + 1] - 1L
  
  ## skip loop if the first two A's were sequential
  if (start_ind == end_ind)
    continue 
  
  this_which_B = which_B[which_B > start_ind & which_B <= end_ind]
  if (length(this_which_B) > 1) {
    ## If there is more than one result and the first B is next to our A,
    ## we need to change it to C. Otherwise, we change all except the first 
    ## B to C.
    if (this_which_B[1L] == start_ind + 1L)
      new_y[this_which_B[-2L]] = "C"
    else
      new_y[this_which_B[-1L]] = "C"
  } 
}

expected_results <- c("A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "C", "C", "B", "C")
all.equal(new_y, expected_results)
#> [1] TRUE
```